# SQL Query / Herigate data join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, the first with person data

```
ID
Name
```

The second has each person relatives

```
Primary Key Field
Person (references person.id)
RelativeType (mother or father)
Parent (references person.id)
```

I'm trying to get all the sons and grandsons of a specific person and I'm stuck integrating the grandsons in the query results. I'm using SQL Server.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is a good scenario for the usage of a common table expression (CTE). You can find quite a few examples of them on StackOverflow

Comment: You have no field that specifies gender.  Do you mean children and grandchildren?

Comment: I edited the original question, so mother or father is not relevant any more. I just need the whole inheritance tree up to grandsons

Comment: This will show you how to do a recursive CTE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636420/a-real-recursion-with-cte

Answer (score 1):

The query you need depends highly of how many level you have of the Parent-Child relationship. If you can change the schema, I would recommend you turn into using `HierarchyId` which is an SQL Server specific data type. Have a look [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290.aspx).

In the following, I assume you only have 2 levels. Father - Son - GrandSon

```
;WITH Sons AS (
    SELECT pdf.Id, pdf.Name, pdd.Id ParentId, pdd.Name Parent FROM PersonData pdf
    JOIN PersonRelative pr ON pdf.Id = pr.Parent
    JOIN PersonData pdd ON pr.Person = pdd.Id //Selecting all Parents
)

SELECT pd.Name, s.Name Son, 'Son' Type FROM PersonData pd
JOIN Sons s on pd.Id = s.ParentId

UNION

SELECT pd.Name, gs.Name Son, 'GrandSon' Type FROM PersonData pd
JOIN Sons s on pd.Id = s.ParentId
JOIN Sons gs on s.Id = gs.ParentId
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (untested):

```
declare @person bigint = 123
;with cte as
(
    select p.id, p.name, r.relativetype, r.parent, 0 decendantLevel 
    from  person p
    inner join relatives r
    on p.id = r.person
    where p.id = @person --select the ancestor who's tree we're interested in (if we don't want to include the person themselves change p.id to r.parent)

    union all

    select p.id, p.name, r.relativetype, r.parent, c.decendantLevel + 1
    from  person p
    inner join relatives r
    on p.id = r.person
    inner join cte c
    on c.id = r.parentid
)
select * from cte order by decendantLevel
```

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned [recursive CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) is way to achieve this:

```
DECLARE @PersonToFind INT
SET @PersonToFind = 1

;WITH RCTE AS 
(
    SELECT Person, CAST('Child' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS Relation 
    FROM PersonRelations 
    WHERE Father = @PersonToFind OR Mother = @PersonToFind 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT pr.Person, 'Grand' + r.Relation
    FROM PersonRelations pr 
        INNER JOIN RCTE r ON r.Person = pr.Mother OR r.Person = pr.Father
)
SELECT r.*, p.Name 
FROM RCTE r
    LEFT JOIN Person p ON r.Person = p.ID
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a6ec3/1)**

*(this is using mother and father columns before question was edited, so just change to `Parent` where there are `Mother OR Father` checks)*

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers, CTE was the way to go. I taked parts from every answer and ended with this

```
with Sons as (select P1.Person as PersonSon from Persons 
join relatives as P1 on P1.Parent = Persons.Id
where Persons.Name = 'Mary') 

select Id from Persons 
join (
select P2.Person as PersonSon from Relatives as P2
join Sons on P2.Parent = Sons.PersonSon ) as P3 on Persons.Id = P3.PersonSon
union all select Sons.PersonSon from Sons
```