# Getting depth-first traversal insted of breadth first in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, recursion, common-table-expression

I have the following T-SQL function: https://gist.github.com/cwattengard/11365802

This returns data in a breadth-first traversal. Is there a simple way to make this function return its data in a depth-first traversal? I have a treeview-component that excpects this (legacy system).

I already have a similar stored procedure that returns the tree in a depth-first traversal, but it's using cursors and is really slow. (6-7 seconds as opposed to this function that takes less than a second on the same data).

Comment: Perhaps you are looking something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11637387/569436)

Answer (score 1):

I think I just had a eureka moment. If I add the `Path` variable already supplied by the CTE, and sort by that, I get what I want. The OrgID is a unique ID. So ordering by it would make it sort by the expected output for the user (chronologically) and be depth-first for the treeview.

Answer (score 1):

```
 http://sqlanywhere.blogspot.in/2012/10/example-recursive-union-tree-traversal.html
```

Here's a diagram showing the primary keys for a tree-structured table:

```
                           1
                           |
       ---------------------------------------
       2            93            4          5       
       |             |            |          |
--------------  ------------  --------     ------  
6  7  8  9  10  11 12 13  14  15 16 17     18  19
   |                   |             |      |
 -----               -----         -----  -----
 27 26               25 24         23 22  21 20
```

Here's what the breadth-first and depth-first queries should return:

```
Breadth-First  Depth-First
1              1
2              2
93             6
4              7
5              27
6              26
7              8
8              9
9              10
10             93
11             11
12             12
13             13
14             25
15             24
16             14
17             4
18             15
19             16
27             17
26             23
25             22
24             5
23             18
22             21
21             20
20             19
```

Answer (score 0):

If you order the output by `tekst`  will that do it?

First populate a table variable `@unsorted` inside the function; then finally return `Select * from @unsorted order by tekst`?

Comment: No, the Tekst-column is the name of the node (it's an organisational hierarchy). So that would only give me an alphabetic sort.

Comment: But it looked to me like @returnTable.Tekst ended up containing the full Path.

Comment: Yes, it did. However the path never gets returned from the function. And it would sort it correctly but wrong :P But I used this method with a zero-padded ID to get the correct sort. So your answer is correct in spirit :) You might just get it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very late to the game, but seems like you could use hierarchyid to get a nice depth first search...

The github file referenced in the op appears to have gone missing, but the basic formula is

1. Put hierarchyid::GetRoot() as Foo in your CTE anchor query
2. Put cast (cte.Foo.ToString() + cast(row_number() over(order by ) as varchar) + '/' as hierarchyid) as Foo in your recursive query
3. order By Foo when you invoke the CTE

and the results come out depth first